# When coloring table rows, there is white space between the line and the \toprule and the \bottomrule

Tags: tables, color, booktabs

As stated in the headline, I am trying to add color to my tables but it seems the *booktab package* leave extra white space between \toprule and \bottomrule that are not covered by \xcolor
[image: picture]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\rowcolors{1}{green}{blue}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\toprule
foo&foo\\
bar&bar\\
foo&bar\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

The problem does not occur when I used \hline instead. I would like to know if there is an easy fix and if it is not too much trouble, an explanation of what is going on here?Thanks in advance.

Comment: [How to remove the space after \midrule in a table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/381718/134144)  is closely related.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/486181/color-a-table-with-toprule-and-cmidrule

Comment: Here's a general (typographic) rule of thumb: Don't mix-and-mismatch visual metaphores. If you use color to highlight various rows of a table, it should not be necessary to use `\toprule`, `midrule` and `\bottomrule` to provide further visual structure.

Answer (score 5):

The space is left over by the toprule and bottom rule-- which space can be separately colred by the command `\aboverulesepcolor` and `\belowrulesepcolor` set to the same color as the `\rowcolor`
[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 

% set line spacing 
\usepackage{setspace} 
\setstretch{1.15} 
\usepackage{relsize} 

% table materials 
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage{multirow} 

% define colours 
\usepackage{xcolor, colortbl} 
\definecolor{my-blue}{RGB}{83,87,118} 

\usepackage{microtype} 

\newcommand*{\belowrulesepcolor}[1]{% 
  \noalign{% 
    \kern-\belowrulesep 
    \begingroup 
      \color{#1}% 
      \hrule height\belowrulesep 
    \endgroup 
  }%
} 
\newcommand*{\aboverulesepcolor}[1]{% 
  \noalign{% 
    \begingroup 
      \color{#1}% 
      \hrule height\aboverulesep 
    \endgroup 
    \kern-\aboverulesep 
  }%
} 

\begin{document} 

\begin{center} 
\begin{tabular}{ccc} 
\toprule 
\belowrulesepcolor{green} 
\rowcolor{green} Variable &  Field One &  Field Two \\ 
\aboverulesepcolor{green} 
\midrule 
\belowrulesepcolor{blue} 
\rowcolor{blue}A & 0.0002 & 0.0005 \\ 
\aboverulesepcolor{blue}
\bottomrule  
\end{tabular} 
\end{center} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: The colors appear to bleed beyond the width of the table when using `longtable`. Any solution so works with `longtable`?

Comment: please ask a new question to attract a larger audience

Answer (score 4):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`, you have directly (after two compilations) the result you wish:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xcolor}    
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{NiceTabular}{ll}
\CodeBefore 
   \rowcolors{1}{green!15}{blue!15}
\Body
\toprule
foo&foo\\
bar&bar\\
foo&bar\\
\bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}    
\end{document}
```

[image: Result of the above code]