# rows of alternating colors in longtable: filling whitespace depending on the row number

Tags: longtable, booktabs, rowcolor, threeparttablex

I'm using the `longtable` package along with `booktabs`-style rules and alternating row colors. The MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{ThreePartTable}
    \rowcolors{2}{white}{gray}
    \begin{longtable}{p{.333\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}p{.333\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}p{.333\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}}
        \caption{Lorem Ipsum.}\\
        \toprule
            Lorem & Ipsum & Dolor\\
            \midrule
        \endfirsthead
            Lorem & Ipsum & Dolor\\
            \midrule
        \endhead
            \hline 
            \multicolumn{3}{r}{(\emph{continued on next page})} \\
        \endfoot
            \bottomrule
        \endlastfoot
            foo & bar & foo\\
            foo & bar & foo\\
            foo & bar & foo\\
            foo & bar & foo\\
            foo & bar & foo\\
            foo & bar & foo\\
            foo & bar & foo\\
            foo & bar & foo\\
            foo & bar & foo\\
            foo & bar & foo\\
            foo & bar & foo\\
            foo & bar & foo\\
            foo & bar & foo\\
            foo & bar & foo\\
            foo & bar & foo\\
            foo & bar & foo\\
            foo & bar & foo\\
            foo & bar & foo\\
            foo & bar & foo\\
            foo & bar & foo\\
            foo & bar & foo\\
            foo & bar & foo\\
            foo\newline foo & bar & foo\\
            foo & bar & foo\\
            foo & bar & foo\\
            foo & bar & foo\\
            foo & bar & foo\\
            foo & bar & foo\\
            foo & bar & foo\\
            foo & bar & foo\\
            foo & bar & foo\\
            foo & bar & foo\\
            foo & bar & foo\\
            foo & bar & foo\\
            foo & bar & foo\\
            foo & bar & foo\\
            foo & bar & foo\\
            foo & bar & foo\\
            foo & bar & foo\\
            foo & bar & foo\\
            foo & bar & foo\\
            foo & bar & foo\\
            foo & bar & foo\\
            foo & bar & foo\\
            foo & bar & foo\\
            foo & bar & foo\\
        \end{longtable}
    \end{ThreePartTable}
\end{document}
```

will give:

[image]

There is some whitespace between `\midrule` and the first row as well as `\bottomrule` and the last row on page 3. I learnt from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/545840/18258) that one can fill those gaps using `\belowrulesepcolor` and `\aboverulesepcolor`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{calc}

\newcommand*{\belowrulesepcolor}[1]{%
  \noalign{%
    \kern-\belowrulesep
    \begingroup
      \color{#1}%
      \hrule height\belowrulesep
    \endgroup
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\aboverulesepcolor}[1]{%
  \noalign{%
    \begingroup
      \color{#1}%
      \hrule height\aboverulesep
    \endgroup
    \kern-\aboverulesep
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{ThreePartTable}
    \rowcolors{2}{white}{gray}
    \begin{longtable}{p{.333\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}p{.333\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}p{.333\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}}
        \caption{Lorem Ipsum.}\\
        \toprule
            Lorem & Ipsum & Dolor\\
            \midrule
        \endfirsthead
            Lorem & Ipsum & Dolor\\
            %\aboverulesepcolor{gray}
            \midrule
            \belowrulesepcolor{gray}
        \endhead
            \hline 
            \multicolumn{3}{r}{(\emph{continued on next page})} \\
        \endfoot
            \aboverulesepcolor{gray}
            \bottomrule
        \endlastfoot
            foo & bar & foo\\
            foo & bar & foo\\
            foo & bar & foo\\
            foo & bar & foo\\
            foo & bar & foo\\
            foo & bar & foo\\
            foo & bar & foo\\
            foo & bar & foo\\
            foo & bar & foo\\
            foo & bar & foo\\
            foo & bar & foo\\
            foo & bar & foo\\
            foo & bar & foo\\
            foo & bar & foo\\
            foo & bar & foo\\
            foo & bar & foo\\
            foo & bar & foo\\
            foo & bar & foo\\
            foo & bar & foo\\
            foo & bar & foo\\
            foo & bar & foo\\
            foo & bar & foo\\
            foo\newline foo & bar & foo\\
            foo & bar & foo\\
            foo & bar & foo\\
            foo & bar & foo\\
            foo & bar & foo\\
            foo & bar & foo\\
            foo & bar & foo\\
            foo & bar & foo\\
            foo & bar & foo\\
            foo & bar & foo\\
            foo & bar & foo\\
            foo & bar & foo\\
            foo & bar & foo\\
            foo & bar & foo\\
            foo & bar & foo\\
            foo & bar & foo\\
            foo & bar & foo\\
            foo & bar & foo\\
            foo & bar & foo\\
            foo & bar & foo\\
            foo & bar & foo\\
            foo & bar & foo\\
            foo & bar & foo\\
            foo & bar & foo\\
        \end{longtable}
    \end{ThreePartTable}
\end{document}
```

Which will give:

[image]

However, the first row on page 2 will also be preceded by a gray bar, although the first row is white. Is there any chance to make this more robust, i.e. by using some if-else-statement using the current row number? Thanks.

Comment: How about removing the extra vertical spaces by `\setlength{\aboverulesep}{0pt}\setlength{\belowrulesep}{0pt}`? Since rows are filled with color, keeping rows with equal height seems reasonable.

Comment: You are right, you can get rid of the whitespace by doing so. But, as a matter of fact, I do like the visual appeal of booktabs-style tables and would like to preserve the spacing introduced with the different rules. Could have mentioned that in my initial post.

Comment: The number of current line is stored in TeX count `\rownum`, but `\endhead` and `\endfoot` both stores collected staff in a box, hence everything is pre-expanded before the head/foot is inserted. Not sure if this can be easily solved/hacked.

Comment: Why don't you just write `foo & &\\ ` instead of `foo\newline`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An altetnative solution with the new LaTeX3 package [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtblr}[
  caption = {Lorem Ipsum},
  note{a} = {First note.},
  note{b} = {Second note.},
]{
  colspec={XXX},
  row{odd} = {gray8},
  row{1} = {white},
  rowhead = 1,
  rowsep = 1pt,
}
\toprule
    Lorem & Ipsum & Dolor\\
\midrule
    foo & bar & foo\\
    foo & bar & foo\\
    foo & bar & foo\\
    foo & bar & foo\\
    foo & bar & foo\\
    foo & bar & foo\\
    foo & bar & foo\\
    foo & bar & foo\\
    foo & bar & foo\\
    foo & bar & foo\\
    foo & bar & foo\\
    foo & bar & foo\\
    foo & bar & foo\\
    foo & bar & foo\\
    foo & bar & foo\\
    foo & bar & foo\\
    foo & bar & foo\\
    foo & bar & foo\\
    foo & bar & foo\\
    foo & bar & foo\\
    foo & bar & foo\\
    foo & bar & foo\\
    foo\newline foo & bar & foo\\
    foo & bar & foo\\
    foo & bar & foo\\
    foo & bar & foo\\
    foo & bar & foo\\
    foo & bar & foo\\
    foo & bar & foo\\
    foo & bar & foo\\
    foo & bar & foo\\
    foo & bar & foo\\
    foo & bar & foo\\
    foo & bar & foo\\
    foo & bar & foo\\
    foo & bar & foo\\
    foo & bar & foo\\
    foo & bar & foo\\
    foo & bar & foo\\
    foo & bar & foo\\
    foo & bar & foo\\
    foo & bar & foo\\
    foo & bar & foo\\
    foo & bar & foo\\
    foo & bar & foo\\
    foo & bar & foo\\
\bottomrule
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

How about this solution? It seems like the `longtable` package executes code in a funny way, which means some workarounds are needed to get it right. If you are OK with it, I think this should be enough.

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{xcolor, colortbl}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}


% define some colors
\definecolor{colora}{HTML}{00bfff}
\definecolor{colorb}{HTML}{ffffff}
\definecolor{colorc}{HTML}{00ff7f}
\definecolor{colord}{HTML}{ffffff}


\ExplSyntaxOn

% set up the list of colors to be used
\clist_new:N \l_colors_clist
\clist_set:Nn \l_colors_clist {colora, colorb, colorc, colord}

\int_new:N \l_color_ind_int

% the function that computes color index
\cs_new:Npn \__compute_color_index:n #1 {
    \int_set:Nn \l_tmpb_int { \clist_count:N \l_colors_clist }
    \int_set:Nn \l_tmpa_int { \int_div_truncate:nn {#1} {\l_tmpb_int} }
    \int_gset:Nn \l_color_ind_int { #1 - \l_tmpa_int * \l_tmpb_int + 1}
}


\int_new:N \l_list_ind_int
\bool_new:N \l_is_header_bool

\cs_new:Npn \resetlistindex {
    \int_gset:Nn \l_list_ind_int {0}
    \bool_gset_false:N \l_is_header_bool
    \__compute_color_index:n {\l_list_ind_int}
}

\cs_new:Npn \calloneachrow {
    \bool_if:NTF \l_is_header_bool {
        \bool_gset_false:N \l_is_header_bool
    } {
        % increment row counter
        \int_gincr:N \l_list_ind_int
        \__compute_color_index:n {\l_list_ind_int}
    }
}

% this function sets correct cell color
\cs_new:Npn \calloneachcell {
    \bool_if:NTF \l_is_header_bool {}
    {
        % get color name
        \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl { \clist_item:Nn \l_colors_clist {\l_color_ind_int} }
        % use this color
        \exp_args:No \cellcolor {\l_tmpa_tl}
    }
}

% suppress color in header
\cs_new:Npn \callonheader {
    \bool_gset_true:N \l_is_header_bool
}


\ExplSyntaxOff


% unfortunately, using \rowcolor directly doesn't seem to work
% therefore, I use the following workaround:

% declare a new column type, which calls \calloneachcell every time
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\calloneachcell}c}

% set list index to 0
\resetlistindex
\begin{longtable}{CCC<{\calloneachrow}}
\caption{Caption}\\
\toprule
\callonheader %suppress background color for headers
% here, I need to explicitly execute \cellcolor{white}
% because the code of column type C will be executed
% before \callonheader, which means the first cell will
% have background color. I simply just override it with
% white color.
\cellcolor{white} Lorem & Ipsum & Dolor\\
\midrule
\endfirsthead
\callonheader %suppress background color for headers
\cellcolor{white} Lorem & Ipsum & Dolor\\
\midrule
\endhead
\hline 
\multicolumn{3}{r}{(\emph{continued on next page})} \\
\endfoot

\bottomrule
\endlastfoot
foo & bar & foo\\
foo & bar & foo\\
foo & bar & foo\\
foo & bar & foo\\
foo & bar & foo\\
foo & bar & foo\\
foo & bar & foo\\
foo & bar & foo\\
foo & bar & foo\\
foo & bar & foo\\
foo & bar & foo\\
foo & bar & foo\\
foo & bar & foo\\
foo & bar & foo\\
foo & bar & foo\\
foo & bar & foo\\
foo & bar & foo\\
foo & bar & foo\\
foo & bar & foo\\
foo & bar & foo\\
foo & bar & foo\\
foo & bar & foo\\
% need to use a \parbox to wrap around \newline
\parbox{3ex}{foo\newline} & bar & foo\\
foo & bar & foo\\
foo & bar & foo\\
foo & bar & foo\\
foo & bar & foo\\
foo & bar & foo\\
foo & bar & foo\\
foo & bar & foo\\
foo & bar & foo\\
foo & bar & foo\\
foo & bar & foo\\
foo & bar & foo\\
foo & bar & foo\\
foo & bar & foo\\
foo & bar & foo\\
foo & bar & foo\\
foo & bar & foo\\
foo & bar & foo\\
foo & bar & foo\\
foo & bar & foo\\
foo & bar & foo\\
foo & bar & foo\\
foo & bar & foo\\
foo & bar & foo\\
\end{longtable}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort! I didn't quite understand the suggestion made by @AndréC above. However, taking into account your answer, I'm afraid that I obviously wasn't able to describe the problem in a proper manner. Your suggestion is perfect to introduce three alternating row colors! However, I'm perfectly fine with two colors. My question aimed at filling the whitespace introduced below `\midrule` and above `\bottomrule`. See page 3 of the first image. You can see the unpleasant spacing also from your example (whitespace between `\midrule` and the first rows). Sorry for being unprecise.